# How to call AsyncTask recursively in android?

Tags: android, recursion, android-asynctask

i tried both the links : [Starting AsyncTask recursively after a gap of 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252717/starting-asynctask-recursively-after-a-gap-of-5-minutes?answertab=active#tab-top)  and [Need advice new AsyncTask recursive calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004276/need-advice-new-asynctask-recursive-calling)

but they didnt solve my problem.
i want to use asynctask recursively after every 10sec of gap. 
iam creating an app in which a dialog box shows with some content whenever some condition full fill and i need to change that content for that i am trying to call asynctask with a combination of thread and handler.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Please show your code so it can be reviewed and someone can help you based on what you're missing.

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) call an AsyncTask "recursively." Maybe you just chose the wrong word? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @323go sorry guys for the late reply..... i think u r right i shouldnt call an AsyncTask recursively.... i am trying to popup a dialog box with some alarms data that come from a url and we can dismiss the dialog box..... i want to check the url after 10 sec, to find new alarm data and when i received new data the popup will come again. thats what i am trying to do.

Comment: hey guys.... is it possible that an application run on phones but crash on tablets with an exception: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()....

Answer (score 2):

```
This repeats every 1000ms:
handler must be final as it is accessed within inner class

final Handler handler = new Handler();
Thread threadObj = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

        // Asynctask

        // delay
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};


//to start thread
threadObj.start();


//to stop thread
handler.removeCallbacks(threadObj);
```

Comment: best answer for novice developer

Answer (score 0):

Create a runnable where you start the asynctask again and again and the start the task for the first time by calling  handler.postDelayed(repeatingTask , 1000);

```
private Runnable repeatingTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         new MyAsyncTask().execute("my String");

                      handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

This way the runnable will be repeated again and again.Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void recur()
{
private Runnable repeat = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         new AsycnCaller().execute();

                      handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};

}
```

**call this function** where you want **Start** 
and also **call this in postexecution of asyntask**